# Angular2: Define a global variable and use it across the application

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 application, In index.html, I am getting my logged in user information from the parent application.

```
var userId = parent.window.userId
```

I need to append this user id to all the API calls. 
Can define a property globally and assign that value here.

Comment: What's 'parent application'? In SPA applications the framework (Angular 2) application is supposed to be parent application. Please, provide the necessary details to understand your case.

Comment: In my scenario,this Angular 2 app will be hosted inside a platform. There will be many other applications along with this. Platform will have single -signon and my angular2 app has to use the user info by parent.window.userId in my index.html.

Comment: What is `parent`? Is it a global, i.e. `window.parent`? What is `parent.window` then? There's just not enough data. You're trying to describe some scenario that exists in your head. Other people can't get there (and they shouldn't). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can build an Angular service. A service is a singleton, so any variables declared in the service are accessible from anywhere in the application.